# Doubts about SAP Mobile Platform

Tags: cordova, odata, sencha-touch-2, sap-smp

I am starting a new app with Sencha Touch in the front-end side and SAP in the back-end side, we will use SMP3 (Sap mobile platform) for this purpose and kapsel plugins to implement in this cordova app, question is.. from point of view as front-end developer I have the kapsel package plugins in a folder and I am using this plugins on the mobile device but:

1. What does it add SMP in my front-end development?
2. What is SMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide more information on the requirement.

SMP is a platform that makes an app enterprise ready by providing easy ways to add enterprise level features to your mobile app.
Some of the major features are-

1. Security - In an enterprise there will be multiple standard security mechanisms used like LDAP, SSO, SAML, Certificate based authentication etc. These security mechanisms could be easily added to mobile apps.
2. Logging, Tracing - When there are many mobile app users it is not easy to troubleshoot issues they face in their mobile app. SMP provide access to the logs in the mobile devices remotely hence it is easy to troubleshoot the issue.
3. Push Notifications.
4. Offline - Limited connectivity in the mobile devices do not stop the users using the app. With the offline feature the user could do the transactions, when the device come to online all the transactions did in offline will be pushed to the backend server.
5. App lifecycle management.
6. Encrypted storage and many more.

With SMP you will be able to add all the enterprise level features quickly. For kapsel plugins the how to guide exists here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-65386